# How to resolve SAS macro variable in shell script

Tags: shell-script, macro, sasl

I am running a shell script via X command within a SAS macro. I want to use a macro variable defined in SAS macro, in my shell script. I know if I pass that macro variable as parameter to shell script, I can resolve that within X command.

For example, the following will work fine, I know:

```
%macro a;

%let var1=test;

X "abc.sh &var1";

%mend;
%a;
```

with this shell script:

```bash
echo "value is $1" >  myfile.txt
```

---

### What I want:

```
%macro a;

%let var1=test;

X "abc.sh";

%mend;

%a;
```

with this shell script:

```bash
echo "value is &val1" >  myfile.txt
```

---

Is there any way to resolve macro variable in shell script? I did my research but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The shell is not going to be able to resolve a variable from an external macro system, such as `&val1`, like you suggest in your example.

You *can* have the shell use values from the environment. For instance, if you export a variable `VAR1` with contents `test`, then you could use this in `abc.sh`:

```
echo "value is $VAR1" >myfile.txt
```

(I'm only using all uppercase as that's the usual convention for exported variables in the shell, using a lowercase `$var1` would be fine, as long as the name you export is also lowercase.)

How to export a variable from SAS is something you'll need to figure out (I have no experience with SAS.) It *seems* that SAS supports a `setenv` statement or command. `setenv` is typically used by some shells to export variables, so that's where I'd look if I was trying to export a variable myself.